# Cocos2d CCActionManager Resume All Actions

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

This has been driving me up the wall! I'm sure that there will be a UBER simple answer, but I just can't figure it out!

Using CCActionManager, I have paused all actions currently running on the screen successfully. My Question is, how do I get them running again?

P.S, I have tried pauseTarget:self, but it doesn't stop all the actions currently running for some reason?

Here is my code:

```
    if (backOrNot == NO) {
Pencil = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Pencil.png"];
Pencil.position = ccp(MainChar.position.x, MainChar.position.y + 10);
id action = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:3 position:ccp(Pencil.position.x, 550)];
    [action setTag:4];
[Pencil runAction:action];
[self addChild:Pencil z:2 tag:4];
NSLog(@"Pencil Shot!");
    [[CCActionManager sharedManager] resumeTarget:self];
}
else{
    [[CCActionManager sharedManager] pauseAllRunningActions];
}
```

I am trying to stop all Pencils (Of which there are many) when I go into Pause, or when backOrNot is returned YES.

**EDIT:**

The problem was SO easy to fix; my point was to get a pause to work. For all of those wondering, you do this:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector]pause];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct, there's a simple answer! :)

Pausing all actions returns a NSMutableSet with the paused actions:

```
CCActionManager* am = [CCActionManager sharedManager];
NSSet* pausedActions = [am pauseAllRunningActions];
```

Later you can unpause those paused actions from the set:

```
[am resumeTargets:pausedActions];
pausedActions = nil;
```

Make sure to use a strong reference for (non-ARC: retain) pausedActions and nil (non-ARC: release and nil) pausedActions after resume. The set's contents are only valid until the actions are resumed, if you keep the set the actions won't deallocate after they've completed.

pauseTarget:self will work, it's what the CCNode class is using if you run [self pauseSchedulerAndActions] and that definitely works.

Comment: Great Answer! The only problem that I encounter while running your code is that, when it resumes, the new actions start, but the old objects don't resume their actions?

Comment: Could this possibly be because my code doesn't have multiple objects, just one object that is "shot" repetitively?

Comment: OH... MY... GOSH!!! I JUST FIGURED OUT THAT THERE IS [[CCDIRECTOR SHAREDDIRECTOR]PAUSE/RESUME];!!!! @#$%^&*(&^%$#@!!!!!!